# How do I know which partition my Ubuntu installation is on?

Tags: 13.04, xubuntu

I have Ubuntu 13.04 and Xubuntu on my hard drive and both of them are EXT file systems. How can I find out which is which?

Comment: You can read the contents of `/etc/fstab`, which contains the *default* partitions for the system you are running. This is a good time to tell you that you can "label" your partitions in GParted (for example). This is just giving them names so it is easier to identify one another.

Answer (score 1):

i recommend that you use `gparted` to get an overview over your partitions.
look at the mountpoints, and especially at a partition mounted at `/`.

alternatively you can use the `mount` command but the output is somewhat less visual.

Answer (score 1):

You can read the contents of `/etc/fstab`, which contains the *default* partitions for the system you are running.

Another way is running:

```
sudo blkid -olist
```

on a terminal and reading the mount point column. (It is preferable if you have the terminal maximized, so the output fits.)

This is also a good time to tell you that you can "label" your partitions in GParted (for example). This is just giving them names so it is easier to identify one another. You can only label a partition which is not in use, i. e., you would be able to label Ubuntu's partitions from Xubuntu, but not from Ubuntu itself.

Answer (score 1):

Run this command in a terminal:

```
mount
```

You will get an output like this:

```
/dev/sda1 on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
```